# Sum of All Odd numbers C#

Tags: c#

I have an assignment to input random numbers from the keyboard that is different from 0 and random number k. I need to find the sum of the odd numbers + k(if k is also odd). Also when typing the numbers only when 0 is being typed the typing of numbers is interrupted. This is what I've got so far!

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int k;
        int min;
        int max;
        int odd = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of k: ");
        k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter minimum integer: ");
        min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter maximum integer: ");
        max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Odd: ");
        for (int x = min; x <= max; x++)
        {
            if (x % 2 != 0)
            {
                Console.Write(x);
                Console.Write(" + ");
                odd += x;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Odd Numbers + K: ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        {
            if (k % 2 !=0)
            {
                Console.Write(k);
                Console.Write(" + ");
                odd += k;
            }
        }

        Console.Write("= ");
        Console.Write(odd + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem? There's no question here.

Comment: The problem right now is that the program uses the numbers between min and max and i don't know how to make the user to input the numbers.

Comment: please edit the question so there is no key information down in the comment section.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This code does what you need. It checks the bounds min and max. It finishes when zero is entered and it also keeps the total sum of the odd numbers.

Replace your static void Main() function with this one.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        //int k;
        int min;
        int max;
        int odd = 0;


        Console.WriteLine("Enter minimum integer: ");
        min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter maximum integer: ");
        max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your number: ");
        bool userIsTyping = true;
        while (userIsTyping)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number: ");            
            int userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (userNumber == 0)
            {
                userIsTyping = false;
            }
            else if (userNumber > max)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number is out of bounds: greater than max.");
            }
            else if (userNumber < min)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number is out of bounds: less than min.");
            }
            else
            {

                if (userNumber % 2 != 0)
                {
                    odd += userNumber;
                    Console.WriteLine("Current Total: " + odd.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That is not an odd number.");
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("The final result is: " + odd.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```